# Can a cat cut its tongue on an open food can's edge?

Tags: cats, safety, eating, biology, can-food

It would be really convenient and save money, to let my cat "Mucca" clean her wet cat food cans with her tongue - but I'm afraid she might [at least eventually] cut her tongue on the edge of the can (where the top is pulled away from the rest of the can).

**Are cats' tongues tough enough to not be cut by a can's edge?**

I am guessing, for example, they are not as tough as shark skin (even though they may feel similar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cats tongue can get cut on a can. It’s not any more or less tough than your own tongue.

The “toughness” you may feel is just their hairs for grooming and cleaning meat of bones. But cans aren’t bones.

I don’t think it’s necessarily dangerous to let your cat lick the can. It would, however, be best to remove the lid (the sharpest part) and then feel the edges with your finger (carefully!!!!) to make sure the rest is okay.

Alternatively, use a rubber spatula (appropriately, I call these cats tongues) to scrape the remainder of the food off for your cat. This is the safest and most effective option.